# cantor set intervals

Tags: recursion, fractals

I have been trying to figure out how to get the values for the limits of the Cantor set intervals (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)). The formulas that i could find only gave the interval themselves but what i need is only the limits. For example for set number 1 the limits are 0 and 1, for set number 2 the limits are 0, 1/3, 2/3 and 1 and so on. I need to use these limits in some other calculations.

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631333/how-to-generate-a-plot-of-planar-cantor-set-in-mathematica) how to generate these intervals (see the second answer) but there is a problem with this method. In I want to generate say 25 of these intervals, my computer runs out of memory (I have 16 Gb RAM!). I have adapted that answer for my needs to obtain these limits, see below:

```
nCantor=5;
cantor=Block[{nn=nCantor,int,intCantor,rule,a,b},
   rule=Interval[{a_,b_}]:>With[{dd=b-a},{Interval[{a,a + dd/3}],Interval[{b-dd/3,b}]}];
   intCantor=NestList[#/.rule&,Interval[{0,1}],nn];
   int=Table[Flatten[intCantor[[i]]],{i,1,Length[intCantor]}];
   Table[
     Flatten[Table[{Min[int[[j,i]]],Max[int[[j,i]]]},{i,1,Length[int[[j]]]}]],
   {j, 1, Length[int]}
   ]
  ];
```

So for example if you look at element `cantor[[5]]` the result would be:

`{0, 1/81, 2/81, 1/27, 2/27, 7/81, 8/81, 1/9, 2/9, 19/81, 20/81, 7/27, 8/27, 25/81, 26/81, 1/3, 2/3, 55/81, 56/81, 19/27, 20/27, 61/81, 62/81, 7/9, 8/9, 73/81, 74/81, 25/27, 26/27, 79/81, 80/81, 1}`

which is what I am looking for.

The question is: Is there a way to obtain these limits faster? I have looked all over and I am stuck. I can calculate these until `nCantor=20` but I was hoping to be able to obtain the limits for larger values.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

In each step of constructing the Cantor set, the amount of work to be done doubles, which roughly implies that doing the next step takes as much time as all the previous steps together. So you cannot expect to go very deep; moreover, you will get very long lists of endpoints.

Here is a function for finding the new list of cantorlimits from a given list of cantorlimits.

```
nextstep[cantorlist_] := Flatten[Table[(1-n/3) z[[1]]+n z[[2]]/3, {z,Partition[cantorlist, 2]}, {n,0,3}]]

Nest[ nextstep, {0,1}, 4]

(* {0,1/81,2/81,1/27,2/27,7/81,8/81,1/9,2/9,19/81,20/81,7/27,8/27,25/81,26/81,1/3,2/3,55/81,56/81,19/27,20/27,61/81,62/81,7/9,8/9,73/81,74/81,25/27,26/27,79/81,80/81,1} *)

Nest[ nextstep, {0,1}, 20] // Length // Timing
(* {20.9665,2097152} *)
```

Only 20 seconds, so you can go some steps further,

Comment: This is another cool method to get the Cantor set, however I think the limit on my machine is around 22 so that's that! I will try to limit my application to these values. At 20 there are a lot of intervals to use!

Answer (score 2):

Let's try rewriting the code a bit more functionally. This often just helps by itself, but it also just makes the code easier to reason about.

This is just a Map:

```
int = Table[Flatten[intCantor[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[intCantor]}]
```

Is

```
int = Map[Flatten, intCantor]
```

The last line is also a Map:

```
Table[{Min[int[[j, i]]], Max[int[[j, i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[int[[j]]]}]
```

Is

```
Map[MinMax, int[[j]]]
```

And the last line is then just:

```
Map[Flatten]@Map[MinMax, int, {2}]
```

Rule often should be functions:

```
rule = Interval[{a_, b_}] :> With[{dd = b - a}, {Interval[{a, a + dd/3}], Interval[{b - dd/3, b}]}];
intCantor = NestList[# /. rule &, Interval[{0, 1}], nn];
```

Is

```
intervalSplit[Interval[{a_, b_}]] := 
 With[{dd = b - a}, 
   {Interval[{a, a + dd/3}], Interval[{b - dd/3, b}]}];
intCantor = 
 NestList[Flatten@*Map[intervalSplit], {Interval[{0, 1}]}, nn];
```

So, I would rewrite the cantor as a function like this:

```
cantor[nn_] := 
 Module[{intCantor, intervalSplit}, 
  intervalSplit[Interval[{a_, b_}]] := 
   With[{dd = b - a}, {Interval[{a, a + dd/3}], 
     Interval[{b - dd/3, b}]}];
  intCantor = 
   NestList[Flatten@*Map[intervalSplit], {Interval[{0, 1}]}, nn];
  Map[Flatten]@Map[MinMax, intCantor, {2}]]
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed reaction but I had to drop this for a bit. I gave your solution a try today but I get this error: "List or SparseArray or StructuredArray expected at position 1 in MinMax[Interval[{0,1}]]." I think this is because Interval doesn't give you a list! That was the problem with my initial approach. I had to transform the interval in a list somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Stan Wagon's Mathematica in Action, chapter 5. There he defines `spawn`.

```
spawn[{a_Rational, b_Rational}] := 
   Module[{w = (b - a)/3}, {{a - 2 w, a - w}, {b + w, b + 2 w}}]
spawn[intervals_List] := Map[spawn, intervals]
```

Then to get your Cantor endpoints use the following.

```
cantor[1] = {0, 1};
cantor[n_] := Join[{0}, Sort[Flatten[NestList[spawn, {1/3, 2/3}, n - 2]]], {1}]
```

There are 2^n terms in `cantor[n]`, so the memory requirements are unavoidable; however, the iterations seem fast enough, depending on your patience. Running `cantor[25]` took about 100 seconds and required only about 3 GB, on my machine.

Comment: I like the spawn function although I don't fully understand it, however I haven't managed to get `cantor[25]` to calculate. Not in 100 seconds! I will use a smaller value. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In version 11.1 you can use `CantorMesh` and get its `MeshCoordinates`:

```
Flatten @ Rationalize @ MeshCoordinates[CantorMesh[4]]
```

> {0, 1/81, 2/81, 1/27, 2/27, 7/81, 8/81, 1/9, 2/9, 19/81, 20/81, 7/27, 
>   8/27, 25/81, 26/81, 1/3, 2/3, 55/81, 56/81, 19/27, 20/27, 61/81, 
>   62/81, 7/9, 8/9, 73/81, 74/81, 25/27, 26/27, 79/81, 80/81, 1}

```
% == cantor[[5]] (* from OP *)
```

> True

Without `Rationalize` it is much faster

```
Flatten@MeshCoordinates[CantorMesh[18]]; // AbsoluteTiming// First
```

> 2.88507

```
Flatten@Rationalize@MeshCoordinates[CantorMesh[18]]; // AbsoluteTiming// First
```

> 14.8317